# mansory js with bootstrap failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

demo http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8301/

```
 var masonryContainer = document.querySelector('#ms-container');
  var msnry = new Masonry( masonryContainer, {
    itemSelector: '.ms-item',
    columnWidth: '.ms-item',                
  });
```

If I detached mansory, the layout is flexible and working fine but the items of a row will both pushed down. So my ideal layout is grid layout that behave like pinterest. I tried mansory before but this time I'm stuck and have no idea how to move on.

Comment: Sorry, but your question makes no sense and I don't see that you demo contains jQuery or masonry.

Comment: How about fixing the demo and we can see your issue?

Comment: @Macsupport I already did, what error in the demo now?